# Writing cross browser javascript code

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

This question may sound like duplicate but its not. So I need to write a Javascript code that will be invoked in different websites where my organization has had a deal with. So different websites across the world, in different devices will call my JS code that is hosted in one of my machine. The JS code needs to pick up many things like url, word count, ad counts, ad location, images count and sizes, user activities like mousemovement, mouse clicks etc, etc.

Now I cannot go on loading JQuery or other libraries for this purpose so I want to write a pure JS code that supports in most of the browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Safari and MSIE and different devices too.

So what is the best approach to write such code.

Comment: Start with coding for Chrome/Firefox/Edge - when that works, completely rewrite it for IE/Safari while banging your head on your keyboard :p

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at the Mozilla docs for JavaScript for every function you use to see what browsers and versions of browsers it's supported on.

You can get started here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript